# Postgres pgAdmin multiple column renames at once

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Is there a better way to rename a column from footballer_id to id. (Removing the footballer_ from all the columns of the table)

```sql
ALTER TABLE public."Footballer" RENAME COLUMN "footballer_id" TO "id"
ALTER TABLE public."Footballer" RENAME COLUMN "footballer_team" TO "team"
```

Comment: No, that's the only way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a query to fetch the column name and then to format and run a command using the results. It makes use of psql `\gexec` parameter.

```
SELECT format('ALTER TABLE footballer RENAME COLUMN %I to %I', column_name, substring(column_name,length('footballer_')+1))
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'public'
  AND table_name   = 'footballer'
  AND column_name like 'footballer_%';\gexec
```

Comment: the `\gexec ` does run the command in a psql shell. Make sure to adjust the table name for your double quoted case sensitive name.

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly better

```
ALTER TABLE public."Footballer"
   RENAME COLUMN "footballer_id" to "id",
   RENAME COLUMN "footballer_team" to "team,
   ...;
```

Comment: You can't combine multiple `rename column` statements like that. That's only possible for `add column`, `drop column` or changing the data type